# Redux reducer reference

Tags: javascript, redux, react-redux

What happens to the state from redux when we trigger an action?

1. We have the current state of redux
2. We call the action
3. Each reducer looks for its own case in the switch that contains the correct actionType
4. Each reducer returns the state - does each reducer return a new reference to the state even in case of default `return state`?

What actually happens to the state if it is returned in reducer? Dose it use some kind of reduce function to compare state and call rerender, then return new reference and react then compare is there any change and invoke rerender?

Comment: I suggest you read a Redux tutorial such as the official one [here](https://redux.js.org/tutorials/essentials/part-1-overview-concepts).

Comment: Or maybe I just don't understand your question. Will you edit it to be more specific? Adding a code example to illustrate what you are asking will help tremendously.

Comment: this is a good tutorial   https://daveceddia.com/redux-tutorial/

Comment: @Rmcr714 While that was a good tutorial at the time, Redux has since changed a lot and the tutorial has not been updated, so it's very outdated in terms of best practices and what we consider "modern" redux. I'd recommend to stick to the official tutorials.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are talking about here is a reducer which is made by combining multiple "slice" reducers through `combineReducers`.  Something like this:

```
const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  users: usersReducer,
  posts: postsReducer,
})
```

Let's say that we `dispatch` an action with type `ADD_USER` -- this is something that `usersReducer` will respond to but the `postsReducer` won't.

> Each reducer returns the state - does each reducer return a new reference to the state even in case of default `return state`?

The `postsReducer` doesn't care about this action and will just `return state`.  This is a reference to the existing object.  So `state.posts` is identical.

The `usersReducer` will create and return a new object for its state.  So `state.users` is a reference to a different object in memory than it was before.  If there are other arrays or objects nested *inside* of `state.user` then those objects will be the *same* references unless we replaced them in the reducer.  So you are dealing with a "shallow copy" where `state.users` is a new object, but a deeply nested object like `state.users.byId[5]` might be the same exact object as before.

---

You might think that the root `state` would *always* be a new object reference when dealing with `combineReducers` since it is essentially doing this:

```
const rootReducer = (state, action) => ({
  users: usersReducer(state, action),
  posts: postsReducer(state, action),
});
```

But [the actual implementation](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux/blob/b3165d0cbd0d8f48142284807d764160df26d6fa/src/combineReducers.ts#L139) is more complex and it involves some checks to prevent unnecessary object creation.  If every individual reducer just uses `default: return state;` then the original `state` object is returned.

Here's how the `combineReducers` function works:

- It has a `boolean` flag property `hasChanged` which is initially `false`.
- It creates a `nextState` which is initially an empty object (so obviously that's a new object).
- It goes through each of the individual property reducers and updates the `nextState` with the updated state for that property.  If the property reducer returned a new state then `hasChanged` becomes `true`.
- If `hasChanged` is still `false` after all the property reducers have been called, then it ignores the `nextState` and instead returns the original `state` variable.
- Otherwise it returns the `nextState`.

---

When using the React bindings like `useSelector`, it (by default) does a strict equality check on the returned value.  So if you are returning a new object which is an exact copy of the previous object, it will trigger a re-render because the object is a different reference.  This is why it is important to use something like `reselect` to memoize your selectors if they involve creating an object through `array.map`, `array.filter`, etc.  Otherwise you will have a new object reference every single time.  `useSelector` also supports [custom equality checks](https://react-redux.js.org/api/hooks#equality-comparisons-and-updates) so that you have control over when re-renders occur.